# Abstract class ArrayList toString

Tags: java, abstract-class, tostring, extends

Ok guys I have an abstract Instrument class

```
public abstract class Instrument {
String name;

public Instrument(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void warmUp() {
    System.out.println("Do re mi"); 
}
public abstract String Play(String notes);
}
```

I use a Sax and Trumpet class to extend and implement the abstract method

```
public class Trumpet extends Instrument {

public Trumpet(String name) {
    super(name);
}
public String play(String notes) {
    String str;
    str = name + " plays Trumpet: " + notes;
    return str;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public String toString(){
    String str = name + " plays Trumpet: " + notes ;
    return str;
}
```

Sax

```
public class Sax extends Instrument {

public Sax(String name) {
    super(name);
}
    public String play(String notes) {
    String str;
    str = name + " plays Trumpet: " + notes;
    return str;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public String toString(){
    String str = name + " plays Sax: " + notes ;
    return str;
}
```

}
Now I need to create a band class that creates a band composed of Trumpets and Saxs. It allows the user to add an instrument (sax or trumpet) and play an input note. When the band plays this means all instruments should play the input note.

```
public class Band extends Instrument{
ArrayList<Instrument> myBand = new ArrayList<Instrument>();

public Band(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public void addInstrument(Instrument a) {
    myBand.add(a);
}

public String play(String notes) {
    for(Instrument inst : myBand) {
        inst.play(notes);
        System.out.println(inst.play(notes));
    }
    return toString();

}
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be in an arrayList, I just thought it would make things easier to handle. I believe I have everything straight so far, but my problem comes in the Play method of band, it should display the play the name of instrument, with all instruments playing same note.

Sample Driver:

```
myBand.addInstrument (new Sax("Anna"));                        
myBand.addInstrument (new Trumpet("Leon"));  
myBand.addInstrument (new Sax("Ben"));

myBand.play("Dum da-da DUM");
```

Output:
Anna playing the Sax : Dum da-da DUM
Leon playing the Trumpet : Dum da-da DUM
Ben playing the Sax : Dum da-da DUM

I know that I need a loop to loop through the array list but not sure how to get the play method from the sax and trumpet class and them all play the same note.

Thanks for any and all help!

I updated my code with the loop but this is the output I'm getting:

```
Anna plays Trumpet: Dum da-da DUM
Leon plays Trumpet: Dum da-da DUM
Ben plays Trumpet: Dum da-da DUM
```

Comment: The way you currently have it set up, your loop will only play the first instrument and return. If you want to output what all of them are playing, you should concatenate the return values and return once after the loop is done. For concatenation take a look at `StringBuilder`.

Comment: `Band` probably should not inherit `Instrument`.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Instrument` class declares an `abstract` method called `Play` with a `String` parameter. By doing so, all classes that extend from `Instrument` must either implement the method or be declared as `abstract` themselves.

Because the type `Instrument` has declared such a method, you can call it on any reference of that type.

```
Instrument instrument = new ...// some class that extends from Instrument 
instrument.Play("some note")
```

The call to `Play()` would be resolved through polymorphism and [late-binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). It would use the overriden method in the implementing classes.

---

Java naming conventions state that methods should start with a lowercase alphabetic character and use `camelCase`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think that I have it down to just loop through the arraylist and call the play method. The method has a return type of string, what should my actual return be?

Comment: If the method returns `String` and you want to display it, you should consider using one of the `System.out.print()` methods.

Comment: @user2745043 The `quiz.Sax@381172c5` result you are seeing is the `String` value returned by the `Object#toString()` method, you should implement your own `toString()` method in each of your classes.

Comment: wouldn't my toString basically be my "play" method?

Comment: @user2745043 You wouldn't be able to pass an argument to `toString()`. In your example it seems like you are calling `System.out.println(instrument)` instead of printing the return value of `Play()`.

Comment: I updated the code and seems to half way work, each displays correct name but all instruments are the same. I's the problem in my loop or in the way I am using the toStrings?

Comment: @user2745043 You are displaying `inst.play(notes)` which is the result of the method call. You have copy pasted `trumpet` in the `play()` method even in the `Sax` class. Just correct that.

Comment: @user2745043 You're welcome. Consider accepting one of the answers if they cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the arraylist and call the base (abstract) `play()` method.

The whole point of virtual and abstract methods is that that will call the derived implementation.

Comment: Ok simple enough ha, as for the return type of string what would should I have for return? Would return null work?

Comment: @user2745043: That's a bad idea; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle.  If `Band` is an `Instrument`, it should behave exactly like any other instrument.  IOW, it should return a larger string and not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I need a loop to loop through the array list but not sure
>   how to get the play method from the sax and trumpet class and them all
>   play the same note.

The beauty of inheritance - you don't need to get the play method from the trumpet or sax classes, you just call the `play` method on each `Instrument`:

```
public String Play(String notes) {
    for(Instrument inst : myBand)
    {
        inst.play(notes);
    }
}
```

Try it!